# Can I run an SQL file in Liquibase which contains file reference?

Tags: sql, oracle, maven, liquibase

I am using Oracle SQL and Maven.

I'd like to run the following file:

```
drop table my_table;
/

create table my_table (
  id  number(20,0)  not null,
  text  varchar2(3000char)  not null
)
/

comment on table my_table is 'This is just a test table to see whether the comments could be written to a table';
/
comment on column my_table.id is 'This is the ID';
/
comment on column my_table.text is 'Here should be some text';
/

@..\db\changelog\my_package.pck
/
```

`my_package.pck`  is:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE MY_PACKAGE AS 

  gc_my_date   constant date := to_date('2000.01.01', 'yyyy.mm.dd');
  
  function get_my_date return date;

END;
/


CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY MY_PACKAGE AS

  function get_get_my_date return date AS
  BEGIN
    RETURN gc_my_date;
  END;

END;
/
```

The file where I gave the location of the SQL file I'd like to be executed:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<databaseChangeLog
    xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:pro="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/pro"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-4.6.xsd
http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/pro http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/pro/liquibase-pro-4.6.xsd ">
    <changeSet author="liquibase-docs" id="sqlFile-example_2.1" runOnChange="true">

        <sqlFile dbms="!oracle"
         encoding="UTF-8"
         endDelimiter="/"
         path="../db/changelog/try.sql" 
         relativeToChangelogFile="true"
        
         />

</changeSet>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

The table was created, however, the package not. I run the file of the package with other variable names but after trying to run from liquibase, it didn't changed.

Is there any way to run SQL files in an SQL file. which's direction is written in the way  `@..\<location of file>`?